# Inserindo imagem com JasperReport via parametros

Tags: java, imagem, relatório, ireport, jasper-reports

estou aprendendo um pouco sobre jasper/ireport e estou tendo alguns problemas para gerar um relatorio com uma imagem.

Segui alguns tutoriais que encontrei na internet mas estou cometendo algum erro que não estou enxergando. O meu relatório de teste é extremamente simples. Contém apenas uma imagem. Estou compilando o relatório e passando a minha imagem por parametro, porém quando gero o pdf a partir do relatório o que aparece é

"java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@6df0eb9d"

vejam o meu código :

```
public class ReportGenerator {

/**
 * gera o relatório.
 * @param image {@link BufferedImage}
 */
public void generateReport(BufferedImage image){
    try {
        InputStream input = toStream(image);
        Projeto projeto = new Projeto();
        projeto.setImage(input);
        List<Projeto> lista = new ArrayList<Projeto>();
        lista.add(projeto);

        Map parameter = new HashMap();
        parameter.put("IMAGE",projeto.getImage());

        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();    
        InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("report1.jrxml");  
        JasperReport jasper = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStream);

        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasper, parameter, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lista));
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, "RelatorioClientes.pdf");
    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
}

/**
 * Converte um {@link BufferedImage} em {@link InputStream}
 * @param image {@link BufferedImage}
 * @return {@link InputStream}
 */
private InputStream toStream(BufferedImage image){
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", bos);
        byte[] vetor = bos.toByteArray();
        InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(vetor);
        return input;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }  
}
```

}

Essa classe Projeto possui como atribuito apenas um inputStream representando a imagem, e o seus métodos get/set.

No ireport eu criei um atributo image e no seu expression class defino como InputStream. e no image expression defino o parametro IMAGE que criei.

Alguem consegue me ajudar?

obrigado

PS: estou adicionando prints da maneira que configurei o relatorio no ireport

[image: Parameter]

[image: Campo Image]

Comment: O problema está no relatório. Se está aparecendo isso é porque o método `toString` do objeto da imagem está sendo chamado. Provavelmente vc está usando um campo `TextField` para tentar exibir a imagem ou selecionou o tipo errado no componente de imagem, pois é possível usar  `InputStream, `File` e alguns outros. Enfim, verifique se você está mesmo usando um componente de imagem e se selecionou o tipo correto que está passando para ele.

Comment: utluiz, eu não estou usando um campo textField. eu Adicionei um campo image sem imagem selecionada, para passar a imagem pelo parameter. Anexei o print da maneira que configurei no ireport. Obrigado por responder!!

Answer (score 3):

Eu tenho feito isso e funciona sempre numa boa.

Linhas gerais para tal:

- A field que irá apresentar a imagem, no report deve ser do tipo : `java.awt.Image`

  [image: Tipo da Field]

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- Depois so precisarás enviar a referência do mesmo tipo (`java.awt.Image`).

Isso tem funcionado perfeitamente, qualquer dúvida, da uma dica.

Answer (score 2):

Vou deixar algumas possibilidades, o seu método `getimage()` terá que retornar um `inputStream`, por exemplo:

```
parameter.put("IMAGE",new FileInputStream("C:/suaPasta/suaImagem.jpg"));
```

ou

```
parameter.put("IMAGE",new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(suaImgEmBase64)));
```

O erro `java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@6df0eb9d` geralmente acontece se você estiver passando um parâmetro no `map` de um tipo e no relatório estiver esperando outro.

Answer (score 1):

Passei pelo mesmo problema, então resolvi da seguinte maneira:

```
<image hAlign="Right" vAlign="Middle">
    <reportElement style="StyleSeta" x="1236" y="1" width="10" height="16" uuid="5c3ba9a6-9116-47af-b4c8-231df22634e7">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
    </reportElement>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$V{caminhoImagem} + "SetaCrescimentoOperacional.png"]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

Eu pego adicionei a imagem element no meu relatorio, e no seu image expression eu passo o caminho da imagem dentro do meu projeto, no meu caso a variavel fica:

```
$V{caminhoImagem} = "http://localhost:8080/RelatoriosWEB/
```

E concateno com o nome da imagem `"SetaCrescimentoOperacional.png"`

Então a imagem PNG no caminho: `"http://localhost:8080/RelatoriosWEB/"SetaCrescimentoOperacional.png"` será adicionada ao seu relatorio.

Answer (score 0):

se for um projeto java, dá passar apenas o caminho da imagem dentro do seu resources que também ele encontra quando for fazer a compilação do seu jrxml.

Exemplos:

```
String logoPath = getClass().getResource("/images/logo.jpg");
params.put("logo", logoPath);
```